# Ebean not loads Foreign Key object on second instance of play framework application

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, orm, ebean

I am running two instances of a play! framework app in my localhost on different ports say 9000 and 9001. 
Suppose I have class `A` which has a foreign key to class `B`. (`A` is a member of `B`)

My weird problem is that in **second instance** (which starts running after first one), whenever I access `A` field from a `B` instance, all of fields are null (except the `id`) and seems the Ebean has not loaded the `A` object from database.

Why this happens? Why the object is not loaded in second instance? Does it have anything to do with Ebean L2 cache?

I even tried running the second instance in a vitualBox VM but the result not changed!

Comment: This is how Ebean works. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563438/ebean-manytoone-finder-doesnt-retrieve-all-data-of-related-object

Comment: I understand that but the weird point is that it is just dysfunction in second instance. The lazy loading is just fine in first instance! @VM4

Comment: it's probably because they have the extra data cached somehow. Maybe because you've recently wrote the data.